# POWER BI - Show/hide charts depending value

Tags: charts, conditional-statements, office365, powerbi, display

Is it possible to decide whether to show or hide a chart depending of some value ?

For example, if a row of my column A is greater or equal to 10, we display chart C1 and hide chart C2.

Conversely, if the value in colum A is less than 10, we display chart C2 and hide chart C1.

My research on internet didn't pay.

Comment: I don't think this functionality exists yet, I know you can do conditional formatting on tables/matrices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting but that probably won't be of any use to you.

Comment: Have you tried using bookmarks? You can use it to show the different charts that you need for different scenarios.

Comment: using bookmarks the user will need to filter the data with the slicer and then click on a button for the bookmark, i would like that only by filtering the data the chart hide without a second click

Answer (score 2):

Not without severe DAX trickery and formatting black magic.

You could have a DAX measure that switches the output based on a value, something like..

```
If([DaxToFindAMaxMoreThan10] >= 10, [ChartValues], BLANK())
```

OR

```
Switch([DaxToFindAValue], "X", [Dax1], 999, [Dax2], BLANK())
```

And then the Charts those formulas are in would need minimal Axis features so as to blend in to the background canvas..

Your best bet is a/set of button(s) hooked up to Bookmarks that un/hide your visuals.

Comment: Could you please add some details of how you would apply your suggestion? Where do I enter that DAX code to filter the data? in SSRS id enter an expression in the visibility function field. How do i do this in PowerBi? Thanks.